# AngularJS loading data on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and trying to setup an app that reads an RSS feed and displays the items upon page load.

I have figured out how to have the data loaded and displayed upon clicking a link (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeyfreake/Lzgts/312/)), but can't figure out how to have this happen on page load.

My thought is that I'm not using `$scope` properly or should be using a model.

Any help is appreciated.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeyfreake/Lzgts/312/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call the method `$scope.loadFeeds()` after defining the method itself.

Comment: Damn that was easy. I was attempting the call prior to defining the method. I assumed that when the JS file was parsed, the `loadFeeds` method would be defined, but obviously it wasn't.

Comment: Yes, it will be a normal javascript execution.

Answer (score 4):

you have not called your controller function. just use this code for controller:

```
var app = angular.module('newsFeed', []);

    app.controller('FeedController', ['$scope', 'FeedService', function ($scope, Feed) {

        console.log('FeedController called.');

        //These calls cause errors:
        //$scope.loadFeeds();
        //loadFeeds();
        //this.loadFeeds();
        //loadFeeds();

        $scope.loadFeeds = function () {
            console.log('loadFeeds called.');

            Feed.parseFeed('http://www.rotoworld.com/rss/feed.aspx?sport=nfl&ftype=article&count=12&format=atom').then(function (res) {
                $scope.rotoWorld = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
            });
        };
        $scope.loadFeeds();//you have leave this line pf code
    }]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-init` directive that will call exactly after controller gets loaded & make much more impact while testing a code using Karma & Jasmine.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="FeedController" ng-init="loadFeeds()">
  ..other html here
<div>
```

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzgts/319/)

---

Though the better way would be calling `loadFeeds` method from controller at the end to ensure all the variables & methods have been initialized. You have to mock all the ajax response as mock data.

Comment: @MichaelFreake you will really know how important it is while doing the code testing..